# C++ Exception handling: exception vs. ifstream::failure

Tags: c++, exception, fstream

In which cases do Options 1 and 2 give different results/behaviour?
Are they equivalent in all respects?

I tried with a non-existing `in_out/sample2.txt` to force an exception and they behave the same.

```
int main() {
    string fnamein2 = "in_out/sample2.txt";
    ifstream ifstr;
    try {
        cout << "Reading " << fnamein2 << endl;
        ifstr.open(fnamein2);
        ifstr.exceptions( ifstream::eofbit | ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit );
    } catch(const exception &e) {               // <-- Option 1
    //} catch(const ifstream::failure &e) {     // <-- Option 2
        cout << "There was an error: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you force the code to throw a different exception than `ifstream::failure` you could see the different behavior.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in your scenario.
`std::ifstream::failure` is specialized version of `std::exception` (contains more details) but in your case you do not used them.

`std::ifstream::failure` has `code` method which gives you more information about an error. But if you do not need it, you can use base class.

Comment: Adding to this: `std::ifstream::failure` is a class derived from `std::exception` (actually, depending on C++ >= 11 or not, the inheritance tree changes).
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure